# Is it possible to make a customer group allow to login in Magento backend

Tags: magento

is it possible to make a customer group allow to login in Magento admin panel.  like we  have a customer group  architect . and we want them  to log in to admin  panel and  create their portfolio.

I want to create  a customer  group   name architect. than i want him  to have attributes of customer and some of custom attributes  that  i will add. now  i want him  to login at backend and access   my custom  menu that I  have created  for him only .

Comment: Yes, given enough time and money it is possible. I think you need to clarify your question somewhat. Right now it's not answerable.

Comment: Are you looking for a programmatic solution?

Comment: @Enigmativity . i have edited the question . Please check.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to create a new user group for the admin panel. And then you can assign access/permission to that group.

You can find that option under System->Permissions->Users into Magento admin.

Here is link which shows complete steps to do that - https://www.sieverscreative.com/setting-up-users-and-access-levels-in-magento/

Hope this helps.